# Brakes are Squeaking

Tags: honda, brakes

We have a 2003 Honda Oddessy. We had the brakes replaced by a friend of my dad's, but a week after replacing them, they squeaked terribly. They make much less noise now, but they are still pretty squeaky.

Do we have any options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they were metallic or semi-metallic pads they could just be squeaky.  Also if the installer did not apply grease behind the pads that could cause squeeking. It's not a problem, just really annoying.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to get rid of the squeak?

Comment: Larry below said what to do about the squeek. Though that's for squeek caused from compression. Again, metallic pads will still make some noise.

Answer (score 4):

If they squeal when you are using the brakes, unfortunately your only option is to take the brake pads back off and apply disk brake quiet to the **back** of the pads. It's not difficult to do at all, and it's not very expensive ($2 - $3).

You can pick it up at any parts store, or even on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000HBGH3G)

[image]

It basically insulates the back of the pad (metal) from the caliper (metal) and prevents the transmission of vibration between the two, otherwise the caliper works like a tuning fork and amplifies the sound. And irritating the crap of of you

Comment: excellent! thanks i might need to look into how hard this is to do. I can jack the car up on a lift at the nearby Air Force base.

Answer (score 2):

Might want to check and make sure that the proper anti-squeal shims were installed too.  It's not uncommon for people to throw them out thinking they were part of the old brakes (and they don't come with the brake pads, you have to buy them separately).  If the old ones were reused, they simply could be beyond their service life.